# Google form/appscript - how to jump between section (via appascript) based on answer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to find a way to:

1. add answers in a Google Form based from a Google Sheet (DONE)
2. add the answer of a dropdown based on a previous answer.. (I don't understand how do it)
3. **EDIT other solution** that I'm thinking about is using the section to "jump" to a section with a specific dropdown populated with the correct data.. How can I do this?? :)

NB the dropdown are inside a Google Form (not created by code, but created using the designing tool of Google Form)
Here my case:

| Area | Sub-area |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | SA1 |
| A1 | SA2 |
| A2 | SA3 |
| A3 | SA4 |

The first dropdown is populated with the date inside the column **Area**
Based on the selected answer, let's say A1, the second dropdown should be populated with the elements of the column **Sub-area** that belongs to **A1**
Is it doable? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs

Comment: @Cooper I want have the dependency between the dropdown inside a google form, not inside the GSheet

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Google Forms.  Once the form is started you can no longer interact with it until after submission.

Comment: @Cooper please take a look on my edit :) I'm investigating that solution as alternative..

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms aren't dynamic in the sense that you can change answers midway through a response. I recommend creating different sections, and then jump to the appropriate section depending on what the answer to the first question is. So you would select "Go to section based on answer" for that question, (three dots on the bottom right of the question) and then on each line item answer, have which section number the form should jump to. So if your answer is A2, it would "Go to section #".  And then the question in that section would be the Sub-Area answers.  You could populate those options in each section the same way you did #1.

Comment: Yes.. I'm investigating that solution.. But I want to do it via AppScript

Comment: I know how to do it using the interface ;)